# Array combinations of 0s and 1s

Tags: c, algorithm

What is a good algorithm to fill an array with 0s and 1s combinations. 
For example if I have three columns the combinations would be:
(1 1 1) 
(0 1 1) 
(1 0 1) 
(0 0 1) 
(1 1 0) 
(0 1 0) 
(1 0 0) 
(0 0 0)
It makes a total of 8 rows (I hope I'm right here). 
So how to determine the needed number of rows in advance (depending on the N number of columns) and then how to fill the array out programatically? Any programming language is fine (I tagged C and lisp because of familiarity) it's the algorithm that is needed. Thanks

Comment: Isn't this just a binary counting of the number? The number of rows needed is 2^N.

Comment: Most of the time you really don't need to fill an array, but merely just stream through all/some possibilities. Do note that this is exponential. If `N=32`, that's at least 4GB right there. 4GB of nothing but numbers going from `0...0` all the way to `1...1`, in order. In other words, 4GB of absolutely nothing interesting whatsoever.

Comment: Actually it's 32GB. At least.

Comment: @poly...: 2^32 ~ 4 GB != 32 GB

Comment: @rubenvb: There are 2^32 numbers, each number is 32 bit = 4 bytes, so 16 GB. Sorry, not 32 GB. Still, a lot of memory to store absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: All the answers were very good, I just had to choose one as the accepted answer which is the first. Thanks all.

Comment: Ah yes, I was thinking bitwise, not bytewise. A std::vector<bool> would be more memory-effecient in this case. Of course, std::next_permutation is even better ;)

Comment: @polygenelubricants: 16GB is huge and it's true, it won't help store anything useful, actually it's just for me to be aware of the combination I have to look for (I doubt though I'll reach N=32 or more).

Comment: rubenvb: How do you intend to store a 32 bit number in a single bit / bool? @polygenelubricants is correct, if N is 32 then you need 32 bits for each number, and there are 2^32 of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Count up from 0 in base 2

```
0 = 000
1 = 001
2 = 010
...
7 = 111
```

Answer (score 5):

The number of combinations is simply 2 to the power of N (or `1 << N` in C).  The values are simply the binary representations of the numbers 0 to N-1.

Answer (score 1):

It's `2 ^ (NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)`

Comment: I have 1 bit (1 column).  2^(1-1) = 2^0 = 1.  One bit can thus only be in one state.  0.5

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the number of subsets of a set. You have 3 columns, where each column is a 0 or 1.

You want to know how many rows you'll need.

You have N columns. Let each column be an item. There are two possibie choices for this column, and there are two choices for each column after. Since there are N columns and 2 choices per column, you have 2^N subsets.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cmath>

void converttobin(const int row, const int cols, int** parrbin)
{
    int j = cols;
    int val = row;
    while (val){
        parrbin[row][--j] = val % 2;
        val /= 2;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++)
        parrbin[row][i] = 0;
}

void testfun()
{
double cols;
cout << "Number of columns - ";
cin >> cols;
int maxrows = pow(2, cols);
int **parrbin = new int*[maxrows];
for (int i=0; i<maxrows; i++)
    parrbin[i] = new int[static_cast<int>(cols)];

for (int row=0; row<maxrows; row++)
{
    converttobin(row, cols, parrbin);
    cout << row << ": ";
    for (int i=0; i<cols; i++)
        cout << parrbin[row][i] << '\t';
    cout << endl;
}

for (int i=0; i<maxrows; i++)
    delete [] parrbin[i];

delete [] parrbin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way to fill out the array:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < nRows; ++i) {
        for (unsigned j = i, k = nCols-1; j != 0; j >>= 1, --k)
            bin[i][k] = j & 1;
}
```

just remember to initialize the array to zero.

Answer (score 1):

@polygenelubricants is right with his comment. It's needlessly wasteful to actually fill an array in this case.  If you need a collection, here's an incredibly simple implementation of the List interface that does what you want:

```
class BinarySequenceList extends AbstractList<String> {
    private final int digits;
    public BinarySequenceList(int digits) {
        if ( digits >= 32 || digits <= 0 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
        this.digits = digits;
    }

    public String get(int index) {
        if ( index < 0 || index >= size() ) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        String padded = "00000000000000000000000000000000" + 
            Integer.toBinaryString(index);
        return padded.substring(padded.length() - digits);
    }

    public int size() { return 1 << digits; }
}

//usage:
List<String> seq = new BinarySequenceList(5);
for ( String s : seq ) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

//prints:
00000
00001...
```

Comment: Whoops, just noticed that this wasn't actually tagged is Java as are most questions I reply to.  Sorry for the language irrelevance; the point stands though.